# SharePoint list filter stuck on spinning loading icon in a list of only 11 entries

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list

**Environment**

From the `Site Contents` directory in `SharePoint`, I created a `Custom List` via `New` > `App` > `Custom List`.  I added 11 entries.

**Desired Behaviour**

Click on `Column Name` > `Filter by` and have a list of the unique values to filter by in the `Filter by` panel on the right of the page.

**Actual Behaviour**

When I click on `Column Name` > `Filter by`, the `Filter by` panel just displays a flickering circular loading icon.

This behaviour is very intermittent, sometimes it loads the values to filter by, sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an intermittent problem, it is hard to determine the root cause.

I need to collect the following information to further troubleshoot the issue:

Are you working in SharePoint online or SharePoint on-premise?

How many items exists in your list?

What is the permission of the user who met the issue?

Does user with full control permission will met the issue?

Does the issue exists in all lists/libraries?

Clear the browser cache, clear SharePoint Configuration cache, run IISRest, compare the results.